# OpenJPA executing prepared statement when none exist in the project

Tags: openjpa

I have web project in which I am using OpenJAP for database connectivity. I have configured the persistence.xml and I am able to connect to the database and retrieve the data. But in the console output I am seeing this entry

```
1953  OpenJPA  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 31156635, conn 6888942> executing prepstmnt 9690924 

UPDATE student 
    SET scourse = ?, sname = ?, sroll = ? 
    WHERE id = ? 
[params=?, ?, ?, ?]
```

In my whole project till now I have not added any prepared statement or any update statement. I want to know why is OpenJPA executing this statement and what would be performance implication when I am fetching big data in the range of millions?

Comment: Maybe the project is referencing some config file somewhere in the file system? How did you search for the above statement in your project? maybe search the whole machine. Also if possible, debugging will give ideas as to where the update statement is coming from

Comment: No the statement is not there. The statement changes based on the table which is accessed meaning if the table is "student" it executes above mentioned statement else if the table is "user" it executes the update statement with the columns of "user" table. This is a very known issue in OpenJPA. This is related to enhancement of the data object class files. I am trying out few things once that is done and it is working then I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added following code to my build.xml file

```
<!-- ***************************************************************************************************************** -->
<!-- DO NOT DELETE FOLLOWING CODE. THIS IS ADDED FOR ENCHANCING THE CLASSES AT COMPILE TIME. IT IS REQUIRED BY OPENJPA -->
<!-- Define the classpath to include the necessary files. -->
<!-- ex. openjpa jars, persistence.xml, orm.xml, and target classes  -->
<path id="jpa.enhancement.classpath">
    <!-- Assuming persistence.xml/orm.xml are in WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF -->
    <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" />

    <!-- Location of the .class files -->
    <pathelement location="build/classes" />

    <!-- Add the openjpa jars -->
    <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="**/lib/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
<!-- define the openjpac task; this can be done at the top of the -->
<!-- build.xml file, so it will be available for all targets -->
<taskdef name="openjpac" classname="org.apache.openjpa.ant.PCEnhancerTask" classpathref="jpa.enhancement.classpath" />

<!-- invoke enhancer on all .class files below the model directory -->
<openjpac>
    <classpath refid="jpa.enhancement.classpath" />
    <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="**/model/*.class" />
    </fileset>
</openjpac>
<echo message="Enhancement complete" />
<!-- ***************************************************************************************************************** -->
```

On adding this and setting the eclipse to use this build.xml file to create the WAR file. The objects are getting enhanced and I am not getting the "Executing the prepared statement" Trace in my log also it is not executing the extra "Update" statement.